# Bootstrap carousel template issue with the featurette images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using the Carousel template in Bootstrap and I've added some images in the featurette class. The problem is that when my website runs on mobile devices those images looks very small compared to how they look on desktop.

```
    <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-5">
          <h2 class="featurette-heading">Lorem Ipsum <span class="text-muted">Dolor sit amet &copy;</span></h2>
          <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7">
          <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" src="images/valigia sito.svg" alt="on time clock" draggable="false">
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Could you please take a screenshot and add it to your question? As a mobile screen is smaller than a desktop screen the images will be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support but it was my fault, i don't know why, because i'm not an expert, but the issue was that i was using svg images which get smaller on mobile devices. Now i'm using png images.